# Row wise calculations in Python and add them to the dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame:

```
df_IJR

Out[40]: 
           Date       Close
0    2015-01-02   56.610001
1    2015-01-05   55.744999
2    2015-01-06   54.814999
3    2015-01-07   55.384998
4    2015-01-08   56.355000
```

How do I perform row wise calculation in a loop.
For Example.

```
for i in df_IJR:
    x = 1000/df_IJR.iloc[i,:]['Close']
    df_IJR['Shares']=x
```

I would like to perform a series of calculations and add them to the dataframe in a row and do the same for the rest of the rows.
I would like to make a series of calculations on every row and add that data to every row and determine the available capital for me to make my next purchase. I may have $500 to make my purchase the next day.

Step 1: I make an initial purchase of 105.9 shares from my initial capital of $1000.

```
           Date       Close  Shares_IJR  Capital
0    2015-01-02   56.610001  105.988340     1000
1    2015-01-05   55.744999                 
2    2015-01-06   54.814999       
3    2015-01-07   55.384998       
4    2015-01-08   56.355000
```

Step 2: After a series of calculations, I find that I have $500 capital and I make my next purchase of 8.9 shares on 2015-01-05. The dataframe now becomes

```
           Date       Close  Shares_IJR  Capital
0    2015-01-02   56.610001  105.988340     1000
1    2015-01-05   55.744999  114.957754      500
2    2015-01-06   54.814999       
3    2015-01-07   55.384998  
4    2015-01-08   56.355000
```

Step 3: Again after a series of calculations, I fnd that I now have $1500 capital and I make my next purchase of 27.4 shares on 2015-01-06. The dataframe now becomes.

```
           Date       Close  Shares_IJR  Capital
0    2015-01-02   56.610001  105.988340     1000
1    2015-01-05   55.744999  114.957754      500
2    2015-01-06   54.814999  142.322527     1500  
3    2015-01-07   55.384998  
4    2015-01-08   56.355000
```

Hopefully this clears my request.

Please help.

Comment: Rows can be iterated through using `df_IJR.iterrows()`, but this is considerably less performant and should be avoided in favour of a vectorized solution.

Answer (score 0):

DataFrames have vectorized operations that are more performant and easier to read than iterative solutions.

```py
df_IJR['Shares'] = df_IJR['Capital'] / df_IJR['Close']
```

If I understand your code correctly, this will have the same effect. The value in the `Capital` column for each row will be divided by the value in the `Close` column for each row, creating a new column that is then inserted into the frame under the name `Shares`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I need to be clear in my request. Your answer is correct assuming I have $1000 every time I want to purchase the stock. I would like to make a series of calculations on every row and add that data to every row and determine the available capital for me to make my next purchase. I may have $500  to make my purchase the next day.

Comment: How is the divisor determined? Would it be possible for that value to exist in another column?

Comment: Fansworth. Thank you. That number will depend on what I currently have available on that day. For now, I can assume a random number.

Comment: @JohnDoe Can you post expected outputs?

Comment: @DavidAlbrecht I have made the edits to my original post. Please have a look..

Comment: @DavidAlbrecht any help ?

Comment: @JohnDoe given the examples, Shares_IJR != Capital / Close but the loop you wrote makes it look like that's what the formula is. Why not use `df_IJR['Shares'] = df_IJR['Capital'] / df_IJR['Close']`? If you fill in both 'Capital' and 'Close' then 'Shares' will be calculated.